# ios background location with kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer and GPS Icon

Tags: ios, gps, location, tracking

I'm using UIBackgroundModes = location to track the user location and send data to my server.

Actually, I've:

```
self.bgLocationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.bgLocationManager.delegate=self;
self.bgLocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;
self.bgLocationManager.distanceFilter = 250.0;
[self.bgLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

I've seen that kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer uses the Cell Tower technology as default method to discovery user location.

When my app comes into background state, the GPS icon is still active, and this might worry the user about the battery consumption. Also, I saw that others apps (for example Google Latitude) can turn off the GPS icon.

Where is the right way to develop an application that tracks the user location?

EDIT:
To use startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges, I need to replace my code with:

```
self.bgLocationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.bgLocationManager.delegate=self;
self.bgLocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;
self.bgLocationManager.distanceFilter = 250.0;
[self.bgLocationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

don't I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. The GPS icon is not just to warn them about battery consumption (though in practice, that's the first thing people worry about when they see that icon), but just as importantly, also a privacy warning that their location is being tracked. (To illustrate this point, the location services settings are located under "Privacy" in the Settings app.)
2. Rather than hoping that `kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer` will not drain their battery too much, you might contemplate using the significant change service, which is designed precisely with this purpose in mind. This also has the advantage that it will wake your app when the location changes, which the standard service will not.

As an aside, I wish there was a different color icon or some other visual cue for significant change service versus standard service (sort of like there is for geofencing), so the user could distinguish between the battery draining issue and the privacy issue, but I don't believe there is.

Comment: Thanks for your response. About the first point, I've understand but about the second point, do you mean that I have to replace my code as my last edit?

Comment: @Cecco All I was trying to say was that the GPS icon is not there to say "hey, you're battery is draining" but rather "hey, you're being followed". So your concern about the user perception of the former is valid and all you can do to ameliorate their concerns by telling them you're being as respectful as possible of their battery (e.g. by having a feature in your app's settings that says something like some reference to "low-power consumption location services"). But if location services are on, the icon shows, and you'll just have to do whatever you can to assuage their likely concerns.

Comment: @Cecco The even better solution is to make sure you turn off location services when you don't need it (e.g when app goes into background, if location doesn't change for a bit, etc.). See [Tips for Conserving Battery](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW17).

Comment: I'm referring to this library: https://github.com/dsdavids/TTLocationHandler but when I set startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges when I go to background mode, the didUpdateToLocation delegate function is never called (I'm using simulator). While, if I use startUpdatingLocation, is all ok. So, since I'm using UIBackgroundModes Location, I'm wondering that I need to use startUpdatingLocation (with accuracy Kilometer and distanceFilter to 250 meters) or startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges. Mah.............

Comment: @Cecco I'd suggest trying it on a device. The simulator does a pretty good job, but simulating driving around in your car is not one of them (and it doesn't appear that manually changing your GPS location in the simulator will trigger a new location). I've used significant change service to monitor changes in the background without any problem. But if you use standard location services, (a) be aware that in iOS 6.1 and earlier, you're limited as to how long you can keep a background app running; and (b) compare battery consumption versus standard services.

Comment: But if I use startUpdatingLocation in conjunction with UIBackgroundModes = Location, why I need to be aware in my background app running? Are you telling me that startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges function can works also without UIBackgroundModes? If works, where can I send my location to server when 10 minutes are elapsed? Into didUpdateToLocation delegate method?

Comment: @Cecco let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32448/discussion-between-rob-and-cecco)